# Choosing COLLATION in cross database join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a database in the UK (database 1), which has a default collation of: Latin1_General_CI_AS.  There is another database created by an American company (database2), which has a default collation of SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  I sometimes run queries like this:

```
select Person1.* from database1.Person as Person1
inner join database2.Person as Person2 on Person1.ID=Person2.ID
```

ID is a varchar.  Here is the error:

```
**Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.**
```

I get round this by doing this:

```
select Person1.* from database1.Person as Person1
    inner join database2.Person as Person2 on Person1.ID=Person2.ID collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Does it matter what collation I specify in the query?

Comment: Another good reason for using numeric identity ids.

Comment: Actually this is a fantastic example of why identity ids aren't always great: he's wanting to compare data between two different databases. If the IDs were identities then two people would have different IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns are `varchar` (not `nvarchar`) then they're not going to have data values affected by collation and it won't matter which you choose. If the columns are `nvarchar` then there might be differences for comparison of the more exotic characters AND the performance may differ.

Personally if performance isn't a big deal I'd just use

```
collate database_default
```

for ease of writing and so your code is more resilient.

If performance is an issue then read [this article](http://www.olcot.co.uk/sql-blogs/revised-difference-between-collation-sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as-and-latin1_general_ci_as) and try the queries both ways with Query Plan On and check out the relative query plans.

Comment: Thanks.   I found that article just after posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Performance could be an issue if you force a collation on the larger table because SQL server can't use its index.

Also you may get incorrect results. If one collation is case sensitive and other is case-insensitive, choose different collation may get you different results.